# Cant use my object before dispose

Tags: vb.net

Just like the title said, i cannot use my object if i dipose it, i mean before i dispose it, i cannot use it. here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim hasil(3) As Bitmap
Dim OneClickInsertGbr As New ArrayList

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    hasil(0) = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Robokidz\Google Drive\Tugas Akhir\Data Training\Foto Uang\1K\scan0001.jpg") 'This is my image
    hasil(1) = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Robokidz\Google Drive\Tugas Akhir\Data Training\Foto Uang\1K\scan0001.jpg") 'This is my image
    hasil(2) = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Robokidz\Google Drive\Tugas Akhir\Data Training\Foto Uang\1K\scan0002.jpg") 'This is my image
    PictureBox1.Image = hasil(0)
    hasil(0).Dispose()
    hasil(1).Dispose()
    hasil(2).Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

after i run, it generate error

> Parameter is not valid.

after that check and see what is the reason behind the error, i know the problem is dispose. Because after i delete all of that dispose, it work fine, but the other problem rise.

> Out of memory

i know this error, because i use too many memory.

my question is.

> How to use an object and dispose it without getting that error?

Comment: Firstly, why is the first line included in either of those snippets?  That variable is not used anywhere else so including doesn't help and just makes it harder to identify what's actually relevant.

Comment: Secondly, what are `myImage`, `myImage1` and `myImage2` in that code? Are they the paths to image files?  If so then that's what you should have said because the path to an image file is not an image.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that is itself going to cause an `OutOfMemoryException` to be thrown. There's obviously more to the issue that you haven't described to us.  This is why you need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  That means a description of EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve, a description of EXACTLY how you're trying to achieve it and a description of EXACTLY what happens when you try it.  If you can't post the EXACT code you're using for some reason then you need to create an example that we can run to replicate your issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, i update my question, hope you and others can understand

Comment: I've already provided an answer that addresses the use of `Dispose`. There's still no indication in what you've posted of why you would get an `OutOfMemoryException` and, in fact, disposing of `Images` is not necessarily going to address that.  Disposing objects means that memory can be reclaimed sooner but it still doesn't guarantee that it will be reclaimed when you want more.  If you're creating lots of `Image` objects then you still may need to call `GC.Collect` on occasion or perhaps do something else to guard against exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you dispose an object when you are finished using it.  If you want the user to see an `Image` displayed in a `PictureBox` then you obviously haven't finished with that `Image`, so you shouldn't be disposing it.  If you are later going to replace that `Image` in the `PictureBox` with another one, THEN you should dispose the `Image` that you are no longer going to display because you are now finished with it.

Here's an example of the sort of thing you need to do:

```
Private Sub SetPictureBox1Image(filePath As String)
    If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        'Dispose an existing Image first.
        PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
    End If

    'Display the new Image.
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
End Sub
```